# Macro to add character at end of string without passing source string

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to write a macro which add a char (end function key) at end of the string without passing source string.

**Statement:**

```
LEVEL_ENTRY(level) << "Level1 Message";
```

**Expected macro expansion**

```
LEVEL_ENTRY(level) levelParser(level, std::ostringstream().flush() << "Level1 Message");
```

I am trying like this

```
#define LEVEL_ENTRY(level) levelParser(level, std::ostringstream().flush()
```

Is this kind of expansion (without passing args) possible with C++ macro?

**EDIT**

To make it work currently I am doing like

```
#define LEVEL_ENTRY(level, msg) levelParser(level, std::ostringstream().flush() << msg)

LEVEL_ENTRY(level, "Level1 Message"<< "Message2");
```

Real problem for this is I can't simply change the statement now' it is used in more than 1000 places in the project.

Comment: Your macro is 'valid', but the generated code is not.  The net result is invalid, therefore.

Comment: @sujin - take a moment to re-read your question, your 'expected macro expansion' is invalid C++ and also contains the macro.

Comment: Roughly speaking, if you want to make things work sanely with macros, use macros that take the relevant material as arguments.  You've got 1000 instances of this notation, you say.  So, that should take, oh, a few seconds to fix on a modern machine with `sed`, even if it appears just once in each of 1000 files, and the files are each 20K lines and 1 MiB in total, which is unlikely.  If you (or one of your predecessors) misdesign something, it can require radical efforts to fix it when the requirements change.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't `<<` things to a macro. Macros are handled by the pre-processor and are not seen by the C++ language parser, and macros do not support any kind of `<<` syntax.

> A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro. There are two kinds of macros. They differ mostly in what they look like when they are used. Object-like macros resemble data objects when used, function-like macros resemble function calls.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Kindly look my updated question

Comment: Your updated question still implies you want the macro to extend beyond the arguments passed to it (your expected statement has a ')' after the `<< "Level1 Message"`). I'll write a small edit to my question.

Comment: I can't change my existing statement. Its avail in more 1000 places in the project

Comment: You said you want to produce the following code: `LEVEL_ENTRY(level) levelParser(level, std::ostringstream().flush() << "Level1 Message");` which is not valid C++, and the statement that you want to produce it is `LEVEL_ENTRY(level) << "Level1 Message"`. What you're asking is not possible. Macros know nothing about `<<` and it's not possible to write a macro that arbitrarily adds a closing `)` to the end of a statement outside the parameters passed to it :(

Comment: Macro expansion i expected is valid C++ syntax. i am passing types to standard string stream. Please check my EDIT where how i manage to achieve this.

Comment: Again, you can't do it with a macro, see Bill Lynch's answer for a non-macro solution.

Comment: Thanks For the Clarification

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but there's no macro involved:

```
class LEVEL_ENTRY {
    public:
        LEVEL_ENTRY(level): level_(level) {}
        LEVEL_ENTRY(LEVEL_ENTRY const &) = delete;
        LEVEL_ENTRY & operator=(LEVEL_ENTRY const &) = delete;

        ~LEVEL_ENTRY() {
             levelParser(level, oss);
        }

        LEVEL_ENTRY & operator<<(const char *message) {
             oss << message;
        }

    private:
        int level_;
        std::ostringstream oss;
};

LEVEL_ENTRY(1) << "Level1 Message";
```

Comment: Creating instance of a class for each statement would not be a good idea.

Comment: @sujin why not? you're in fact doing exactly that with an instance of the `ostringstream` class.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve your problem would be:

```
struct Foo { int level; };

auto operator<<(Foo foo, char const *s)
{ 
    return levelParser(foo.level, std::ostringstream().flush() << s);
}

#define LEVEL_ENTRY(level) Foo{level}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for `LEVEL_ENTRY(3) << "foo" << "bar";`, but that may be outside the requirements.

Comment: @Bill Lynch your comment is my exact requirement that is why i am using ostringstream. LEVEL_ENTRY(3) << "foo" << "bar" << var1 << stringvar;

Comment: @sujin do you want the result of all streaming to be passed to levelParser?  It would be good to update the first part of your question to include this usage?

Comment: BTW `ostringstream().flush()` is the same as `ostringstream()`, there is nothing to flush when it is empty